# How do I generate url from image id in databse?

Tags: php, mysql, url

I am new to php and want generate url from image id in database. I have some images in my mysql-database associated with random id eg 546ae8c6b9f9a. I want to show all images related to that image if someone visit the page www.mysite.com/546ae8c6b9f9a. Simular to this url http://sv.tinypic.com/r/v2sak3/8

How can I do that when 546ae8c6b9f9a is not a directory or real file, just a reference to which images I want to show from the database?

Comment: you have image details in DB along with image id right ? Use that to retrieve image

Comment: @CodingAnt is correct. You need to use some .htaccess rules so that when user comes to url www.mysite.com/546ae8c6b9f9a, you should pass '546ae8c6b9f9a' as a parameter and depending upon that parameter, you can show the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below Url.
They might be helpful for you.

[Solution to retrieve image directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20324239/1764454)

[Solution to retrieve image via Url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7793098/1764454)